# Which one is the real single phase two wire circuit?

Tags: voltage, power, single-phase

Which one is the real single phase two wire \$(1\phi2w)\$ circuit? i have seem these two type,and both of them were be written in some books

**Type A:**

https://slideplayer.com/slide/5867350/  0:35 in video

As we can see,this type of \$1\phi2w\$ has just one loading \$Z_L\$,if we assume the voltage of \$V_L\$
,and the impedance of wire is \$R+Xj\$,we can easily know the voltage drop,\$\Delta V\$,of this type of \$1\phi2w\$ and the power which the voltage source transmit ,\$P_t\$,are as below

\$\Delta V=V_p-V_L=I(Rcos\theta+Xsin\theta)\$,\$I \$ is the current flows from the voltage source to the loading
\$P_t=P_L+P_w=P_L+[I^2(Rcos\theta+Xsin \theta)\times 2]\$, \$P_w\$: the power which wire consume;\$P_L=\$loading power

[image]

**Type B:**

https://e.as76.net/asn/tan3.php

As we can see,this type of \$1\phi2w\$ has "two" loading \$Z_L\$,if we assume the voltage of \$V_L\$
,and the impedance of wire ,\$R_1\$ and \$R_2 \$,are both \$R+Xj\$,we can easily know the voltage drop,\$\Delta V\$,of this type of \$1\phi2w\$ and the power which the voltage source transmit ,\$P_t\$,are as below

\$\Delta V=V_p-V_L=2I(Rcos\theta+Xsin\theta)\$,\$I \$ is the current flows from the voltage source to the both loading
\$P_t=P_L+P_w=P_L+[(2I)^2(Rcos\theta+Xsin \theta)\times 2]\$, \$P_w\$: the power which wire consume;\$P_L=\$loading power

[image]

So now i want to ask both of them are said \$1\phi2w\$,however,their voltage drop and the transmitted power are both not the same.So,which one is the real \$1\phi2w\$ circuit?you may say depend on which circuit you choose or the question provide,but the big problem is that the question will ask me about \$1\phi2w\$ without providing a \$1\phi2w\$ circuit

Comment: They are both single phase two wire circuits. It's got nothing to do with voltage, wire impedance, load or current or applied frequency or DC or AC.

Comment: The only difference is that Type B has a transformer that can presumably supply a second circuit to make a three-wire single phase distribution system with two 100V connections that share the grounded common and a 200V connection that does not have a grounded common.

Comment: Type B shows the resistance of the supply wires, which Type A ignores.  B also shows two loads, while A shows one.  You might say that Type B shows more detail, but each one shows what the author needed to show for that example.